# IPython with and Without Notebook Differences

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

One of the most important improvisations of Python that are my favorites are IPython and IPython Notebook.

I was watching and repeating what's shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Fp1zn5ao2M) and found some issues.

As specified in the video, I use `ipython --pylab` to launch IPython.
And I use `ipython notebook --pylab` to launch IPython Notebook.

Issues: `scatter()` would not work in IPython NoteBook (I get a `NameError`) but works fine in IPython.
Same is the case with the function `rand()`. I guess `pylab` is loaded along with `matplotlib`, `scipy`, `numpy`, `random` and other essential libraries.

Please tell me if I am wrong. By the way, both my IPython and IPython NoteBook load from my **Anaconda Dist.**, if that means anything.

Also any resource where I can know what all is loaded when I use `--pylab` would help.

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend against using `--pylab`. Instead use `%matplotlib inline` at the begin of your notebook. Afterwards you can import the packages you would like to use without cluttering up your namespace.

Comment: Thank you and I will remember your advice not to use the flag of pylab. And yes `%matplotlib inline` did work. I now understand more about `--pylab`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `pylab` flag does:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pylab, mlab, pyplot
np = numpy
plt = pyplot

from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize, getfigs

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
```

That said, it is recommended that you launch the notebook without the flag (just `ipython notebook`) and then run:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

For more details see [No Pylab Thanks](http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.ipynb.html).

Regarding your scatter problem, you should try the following:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter([1,2], [1,2])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @elyase. I got it worked. I will sure work around it without using the flag `--pylab`. "No PyLab Please" article is really helpful and my understanding has surely grown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example of why you shouldn't use `%pylab inline`:

Before `%pylab inline`: `bool(all(i for i in range(3))) => False`

After `%pylab inline`: `bool(all(i for i in range(3))) => True`

The `%pylab inline` statement imports `numpy.all`, which has a different behavior. See `help(all)` before and after `%pylab inline` to see. Also, try `print(', '.join(sorted(globals().keys())))` before & after to see the vast number of things that get imported.

As mentioned by others, `%matplotlib inline` avoids this and the subsequent subtle / hard-to-find issues that it causes.